# How to get the query result metadata in sqlite3?

Tags: c, sqlite

Mysql supplies API mysql_fetch_fields to get the query result metadata.

```
MYSQL_RES *result;
...
auto fieldsNum = mysql_num_fields(result);
auto fields = mysql_fetch_fields(result);

for (size_t i = 0; i < fieldsNum; i++) {
    printf("column [%d] name: %.*s\n", i + 1, (int)fields[i].name_length, fields[i].name);
}
```

Is there any same function in sqlite3?

Comment: https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_count.html and https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html

Comment: this is what i want. thks